# WPF grid-like viewer with 'random' types within columns

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

I have to modify a view in an existing app. View looks like a data grid with one exclusion: one of the columns rows might have different data types and different editors respectively. Say, `string`, `number`, `bool`, `enum`.

In existing design this is implemented as a plain grid with appropriate controls embedded into cells. This is more or less acceptable, but arises the problem with header row and scrolling.
I've tried to use `ListView` with underlying `GridView`, looks nice but does not solve the problem with editing.

Here is what I've got now, a `UserControl` in a tab-based app.

[image]

But seems to me it is a dead end and I have no clue where to move next.

Using third party (free only) looks dead end either.

Comment: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid

Comment: The first thing I tried was embedding PropertyGrid from WinForms. Does not work since I need multiple columns,

Comment: Well, you can have a look at the source of the WpfToolKit PropertyGrid how they solved the same problem you now have. Use it or learn from it

Comment: I can of course, but very limited on the budget...

Comment: So you want us to save your budget?

Comment: Appreciate your humor :-) But main asset on my budget is time. I hoped somebody can help me save it...